# Does $\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n=\sum_{n \geq 0} b_nx^n$ imply $a_n=b_n$ for vector-tuple power series?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, p-adic-analysis, multivariable-calculus

My reference is [Infinite series in p-adic fields](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/infseriespadic.pdf) by Keith Conrad.

**Corollary 5.6.** If $f(x)=\sum_{n≥0} a_nx^n$ has a positive radius of convergence in the $p$-adic field $\mathbb Q_p$ then $f$ is infinitely differentiable on its disc of convergence in $K$ and for all $n ≥ 0$ and $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$. In particular, $f$ has only one choice of power series coefficients.

**Proof.** Let $D$ be the disc of convergence of $f(x)$. By Theorem 5.3 (of the same note), $f'(x)=\sum_{n \geq 0} n a_n x^{n-1}$ for all $x \in D$. This is again a power series, so by Theorem 5.3, it is differentiable on $D$ with derivative $f^{''}(x)=\sum_{n \geq 2}n(n-1)x^{n-2}$. By induction, the $k$th derivative is
$$f^{(k)}(x)=n(n − 1) \cdots (n − (k − 1))a_nx^{n−k}$$
for all $x \in D$. In particular, the constant term is $f^{(k)}(0)= k(k−1) \cdots (k−(k−1))a_k= k!a_k$, so $a_k =\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}$. This shows the coefficients of the power series are determined by $f$ as a function around $0$.

Uniqueness follows from Corollary 3.15 of the same Note, and it is not required to use derivatives of $f$.

---

**My question:** Is there generaliation of the above results for vector-tuple power series $f: \mathbb Q_p^n \to \mathbb Q_p^n$?

For example, take the simple case $n=2$ and consider the 2-tuple power series $f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$ defined in the following way
$$f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} f_1(x,y) \\ f_2(x,y) \end{pmatrix}=\sum_{m,n \geq 0} \begin{pmatrix} a_{mn}^{11} & a_{mn}^{12} \\ a_{mn}^{21} & a_{mn}^{22} \end{pmatrix} X^{m+n}, $$ where $X^{l+m}=\begin{pmatrix} x^i y^j \\ x^r y^s \end{pmatrix}$ is column vector and $i,j,r,s \geq 0$ such that $i+j=m$ and $r+s=n$. Also note that $a_{mn}^{uv}$ is the $(u,v)$-th entry of the 2-by-2 matrix corresponding to the coefficient of $X^{l+m}$.

Of course, there can be more different expositions of $f(x,y)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$, for example:
$$f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} f_1(x,y) \\ f_2(x,y) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \sum_{m,n \geq 0} a_{m,n} x^my^n \\ \sum_{m,n \geq 0} a'_{m,n}x^my^n \end{pmatrix};~a_{m,n}, a_{m,n}^{'} \in \mathbb Q_p.$$

Can we generalise Corollary 5.6?

I see the challenge in handling the derivatives of $f(x,y)$. The coefficients $a_{mn}^{11}, a_{mn}^{12}, a_{mn}^{21}, a_{mn}^{22}$ are determined by the mixed partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$ at $(0,0)$.

Can someone shed some light on it? Thanks

Comment: Let me stick to $n=1$. If you project $f$ to one coordinate, you get a power series of the form $f(x,y)=\sum_{m,n=0}^\infty a_{m,n}x^ny^m$. You then keep $y$ fixed and apply the above to $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ and get  a formula for $\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_{m,n}y^m$. Apply the above again to get $a_{m,n}=\frac{\partial_y^{(m)}\partial_x^{(n)}f(x,y)}{n! m!}\big|_{x=y=0}$.

Comment: @Nandor, Yes, I am also getting to such coefficients. Since we can determine the coefficients, this suggests that we can generalise Corollary 5.6. Let me try to write a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Since no answer has been provided so far, I am composing a self-answer. I appreciate suggestions and comments on how to improve it.

We have $$f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} f_1(x,y) \\ f_2(x,y) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \sum_{m,n \geq 0} a_{m,n} x^my^n \\ \sum_{m,n \geq 0} b_{m,n}x^my^n \end{pmatrix};~a_{m,n}, b_{m,n} \in \mathbb Q_p.$$
In the region of convergence of $f(x,y)$, each component $f_1(x,y)$ and $f_2(x,y)$ is infinitely differentiable with respect to both variables $x$ and $y$. So partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$ exist of all orders.

As suggested by @Nandor, take the projection of $f(x,y)$ to the first coordinate so that $f(x,y)$ is of the form $f(x,y)=\sum_{m,n \geq 0} a_{m,n} x^my^n$. Keep unchanging $y$ and define the map $x \mapsto f(x,y)$ by $g(y)=f(\alpha,y):=\alpha^m \sum_{n \geq 0} a_{n}y^n$ for some constant $\alpha \in \mathbb Q_p$ and $a_n$ is adjusted with $a_{m,n}$. Then, using Corollary 5.6 (see in the question), we get $a_{n}=\frac{\partial^{(n)}}{n!}f(\alpha,0)$. Again, vary $x$ and apply the map $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ we get the coefficient $$a_{m,n}=\frac{\partial^{(m) \partial^{(n)}} \partial}{m! n!}f(x,y)|_{x=y=0}.$$

Now we prove the uniqueness of the coefficients $a_{m,n}$. Let us assume $f(x,y)=h(x,y)$ i.e.,
\begin{align} &f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} f_1(x,y) \\ f_2(x,y) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \sum_{m,n \geq 0} a_{m,n} x^my^n \\ \sum_{m,n \geq 0} b_{m,n}x^my^n \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \sum_{m,n \geq 0} a'_{m,n} x^my^n \\ \sum_{m,n \geq 0} b'_{m,n}x^my^n \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} h_1(x,y) \\ h_2(x,y) \end{pmatrix}=h(x,y);~a_{m,n}, b_{m,n}, a_{m,n}', b'_{m,n} \in \mathbb Q_p \\
\Rightarrow & \begin{pmatrix} \sum_{m,n \geq 0} (a_{m,n}-a'_{m,n}) x^my^n \\ \sum_{m,n \geq 0} (b_{m,n}-b'_{m,n})x^my^n \end{pmatrix}=0\end{align}
We just need to show $c_{m,n}:=a_{m,n}-a'_{m,n}=0$ and $c._{m,n}=b_{m,n}-b'_{m,n}=0$ for all $m,n$. We have the power series
\begin{align} &\sum_{m,n \geq 0} c_{m,n}x^my^n=0, \\
\text{and} &~ \sum_{m,n \geq 0} c'_{m,n}x^my^n=0.
\end{align}
Put $x=0=y$, we get $c_{0,0}=0=c'_{m,n}$. Suppose for *small non-zero* $x$ and $y$, we have $c_{M,N}=0=c'_{M,N}$ for $m<M$ and $n<N$. Then,
\begin{align} &\sum_{m \geq M, \\ n \geq N} c_{m,n}x^my^n=0, \\
\text{and} &~ \sum_{m \geq M, \\ n \geq N} c'_{m,n}x^my^n=0.
\end{align}
We want to show that $c_{M,N}=0=c'_{M,N}$. For,
\begin{align} & \sum_{m \geq M, \\ n \geq N} c_{m,n}x^my^n=0 \\
 \Rightarrow &c_{M,N}x^My^N+c_{M+1, N+1}x^{M+1}y^{N+1}+c_{M+2,N+2}x^{M+2}y^{N+2}+\cdots=0 \\
\Rightarrow & c_{M,N}+c_{M+1, N+1}x^{M}y^{N}+c_{M+2,N+2}x^{M+1}y^{N+1}+\cdots=0~(\text{since}~x \neq 0 \neq y) \\
\Rightarrow c_{M,N}=0
\end{align}
Thus, $c(x,y):=\sum_{m,n \geq 0} c_{M+m,N+n}x^my^n=0$ in $\mathbb Q_p$ for all small non-zero $x,y$. Note that $c(x,y)$ is also convergent at $x=0=y$ with value $c_{M,N}=0$. By the convergence property, $$c_{M,N}=\lim_{x \to 0 \\ y \to 0} \sum_{m,n \geq 0} c_{M+m,N+n}x^my^n=\lim_{x \to 0 \\ y \to 0} 0=0,$$ which implies $c_{M,N}=0$. Thus, by induction, $c_{m,n}=0$. Similarly, we get $c'_{m,n}=0$. Therefore, $a_{m,n}=a'_{m,n}$ and $b_{m,n}=b'_{m,n}$. Hence unique coefficients of $f(x,y)$. This completes the rough demonstration.

**Conclusion:** If $f,g: \mathbb Q_p^r \to \mathbb Q_p^r$ be two vector $r$-tuple p-adic power series with positive radius of convergence in $\mathbb Q_p$ and they are equal, then their coefficients are equal, i.e.,
\begin{align} &f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} \sum_{m,n \geq 0} a_{m,n} x^my^n \\ \sum_{m,n \geq 0} b_{m,n}x^my^n \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} \sum_{m,n \geq 0} a'_{m,n} x^my^n \\ \sum_{m,n \geq 0} b'_{m,n}x^my^n \end{pmatrix}=h(x,y);~a_{m,n}, b_{m,n}, a_{m,n}', b'_{m,n} \in \mathbb Q_p \\
\Rightarrow & a_{m,n}=a'_{m,n},~ b_{m,n}=b'_{m,n}.
\end{align}